# $\sum \exp(-n^{ 1/3})$ series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_n \exp(-n^{ 1/3})$ Should be convergent by ratio test. However it gives me that $a_{n+1}/a_{n}=\exp(n ^{1/3}-(n+1)^{1/3}) \rightarrow 1,n \rightarrow +\infty $ so the limit ratio test fails. Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let apply limit comparison test with $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$.

Comment: +1 ... $\exp(-n^{1/3})$ goes to zero faster than $1/n^k$ for any power $k$.  But, of course, for all of these series $\sum 1/n^k$ the ratio test fails.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, really appreciate. Regards